# Windows recovery show disks as RAW, can't run CHKDSK, but Linux sees them normally

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, chkdsk, partition-recovery

My disk is dying (increasing Reallocated Sectors Count) but every time CHKDSK fixed everything untill next time and I'd like to continue like this as long as possible, given that I know all risks and backup often.

This time it was something different. I went for the dinner and forgot to shut system to sleep (so that Windows don't trash hdd like it often does when not active) and after dinner I returned to BSoD. Can't start computer at all, it first loads but then crushes "no bootable device".

I used windows recover usb and found this:
[image]

All sectors are RAW, CHKDSK doesn't help. So it seems like a real RAW (usually CHKDSK knows when it is not real) and that the End has come.

But then I checked linux-based recovery disks "Ultimate Boot CD" and "Boot-repair-disk" and they see hdd as no any problem, everything is NTFS and I can freely browse my files. And now I am not sure that this problem is not fixable.
[image]

TestDisk:
[image]

What else can be done to convert RAW to NTFS, or at least find what is the real problem?
All I need is to run CHKDSK on it.

Comment: Same problem as mine - https://forum.cgsecurity.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=6081

Comment: If you can read the files on Linux, back them up, reformat, done. // I understand that not everyone has the money to replace faulty hardware right away, but you should act on this now, rather than later, backups or not.

Comment: It is not about money, my hardware is not costly, I is about perfectly tuned working system. I heard "replace hdd immediately" 3 years ago when it started.

Comment: I was trying to change partition sizes where it see them normally but it throws errors. I am trying WinPE boot disks but it the same - raw on windows and ntfs on linux. Sadly it can be the end, but I still feel that chkdsk can fix everything like it always did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You commented :

> "It is not about money, my hardware is not costly, I is about perfectly tuned working system. I heard "replace hdd immediately" 3 years ago when it started. –

If you wanted to save your "perfectly tuned working system" you simply had to duplicate your drive. With degradation right now the chances of your remaining system being healthy enough are diminishing.

When sectors start pending and getting reallocated it is like disk cancer.
Luckily this kind of disk cancer can be cured by a disk replacement.

You try to drive a dammaged submarine without being a mechanic.

> What else can be done to convert RAW to NTFS, or at least find what is the real problem? All I need is to run CHKDSK on it.

There is no conversion from "RAW" to "NTFS".
Once essential structures are hit by sector failures you are done.

Lost data on modern drive is lost forever.

Sometimes certain structures can be rebuilt by using their backups.
Lost data has no backup in NTFS.

The reason your Linux ist still handling files is that Linux is less strict when it comes to file system integrity. Microsoft never disclosed NTFS as to know why a Microsoft operating system refuses to work on a volume/partition.

> All sectors are RAW

The term "RAW" only exists on file system level, not on sector level.
There is no algorithm to check if a single sector contains useful content or not, whereas such an algorithm is embedded in the chkdsk command.

> It is not about money, my hardware is not costly, I is about perfectly tuned working system. I heard "replace hdd immediately" 3 years ago when it started.

The more you learn about how data is organized in terms of volumes/partitions and file systems the more you will accept the advice you were given three years ago.

If I was to write you a bill for the explanations I have given to you you would soon realize that it is cheaper to replace your broken which could have been done successfully three years ago.

> no bootable device

If you are not a specialist who knows what this means and which sectors of a disk are related to this information you should at all cost prevent getting in such a situation.

Comment: I'll accept it though it is not the answer, but it seems like there is no answer. I already setting up new system.
It is not as bad as it sounds, just doing backups is like 95% of everything and this disk taught me doing them for good. I had same situation with RAW several months ago and chkdsk fixed it, but it was different. 
Good thing is that now is a good time to move, if it would strike me when I am doing important work it can be really bad.

Comment: I had 325 Reallocated Sectors last time I checked several days ago, it was growing for 3 years. it was a fun ride.